# Pandas - expending several values to new columns with some column name manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to pandas.
Consider you have a state in which you have a pandas `Dataframe` structure of columns like below:

`user_id | timestamp | foo_name1 | foo_name2 | foo_name3`

As we can see `Dataframe` has several metadata parameters, having raw string values:
`user_id, timestamp`
and several **dynamic** name columns - which have a string value of json within each: `foo_name1..foo_name3`

Example for the structure of json within `foo_name1` col (which has a fixed hierarchy, dict keys and values may vary within):

`{"foo_att1": "foo_value1","foo_att2": "foo_value2"}`

So my will is to end up with this kind of DF structure instead - kind of expending:
DF:

`user_id | timestamp | foo_name1-foo_att1 | foo_name1-foo_att2 | foo_name2-foo_att1 | foo_name2-foo_att2`

Whereas`foo_name1-foo_att1` will have as value: `"foo_value1"`
`foo_name1-foo_att2` will have value : `"foo_value2"`
Etc...

How can I achieve this using pandas actions?

Comment: @Quang Hoang: I saw you may know how to resolve such issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I synthesised the structure you defined
2. use `pd.concat(axis=1)` and `pd.json_normalize()` gets you to your answer
3. an additional use of a `dict` comprehension to name columns as per your requirement

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**{"userid": random.randint(1,100), 
 "timestamp":dt.datetime(2020,8,9,random.randint(0,23))},
 **{f"foo_name{f+1}":{f"foo_att{ff+1}":random.randint(1,10) for ff in range(2)} for f in range(3)}
} for r in range(5)])

df2 = pd.concat([
    df.loc[:,["userid", "timestamp"]]] + # the fixed columns
    [
        pd.DataFrame({f"{c}.{k}":v # rename columns as per requirement
                      for k,v in 
                      # json_normalize is doing all the work,  but requirement to rename columns....
                      pd.json_normalize(df[c]).to_dict(orient="list").items()}) 
        # in dict comprehension loop through all foo columns to turn them from dicts to columns
        for c in df.columns if "foo" in c
], axis=1)

print(f"{df.to_string(index=False)}\n\n{df2.to_string(index=False)}")
```

**output**

```
 userid           timestamp                       foo_name1                        foo_name2                        foo_name3
     94 2020-08-09 15:00:00  {'foo_att1': 1, 'foo_att2': 7}   {'foo_att1': 5, 'foo_att2': 2}   {'foo_att1': 5, 'foo_att2': 9}
     61 2020-08-09 05:00:00  {'foo_att1': 2, 'foo_att2': 3}  {'foo_att1': 10, 'foo_att2': 9}  {'foo_att1': 10, 'foo_att2': 4}
     69 2020-08-09 12:00:00  {'foo_att1': 9, 'foo_att2': 6}   {'foo_att1': 7, 'foo_att2': 8}   {'foo_att1': 5, 'foo_att2': 9}
     16 2020-08-09 13:00:00  {'foo_att1': 2, 'foo_att2': 1}   {'foo_att1': 7, 'foo_att2': 8}   {'foo_att1': 9, 'foo_att2': 1}
     51 2020-08-09 11:00:00  {'foo_att1': 3, 'foo_att2': 1}   {'foo_att1': 7, 'foo_att2': 1}   {'foo_att1': 6, 'foo_att2': 3}

 userid           timestamp  foo_name1.foo_att1  foo_name1.foo_att2  foo_name2.foo_att1  foo_name2.foo_att2  foo_name3.foo_att1  foo_name3.foo_att2
     94 2020-08-09 15:00:00                   1                   7                   5                   2                   5                   9
     61 2020-08-09 05:00:00                   2                   3                  10                   9                  10                   4
     69 2020-08-09 12:00:00                   9                   6                   7                   8                   5                   9
     16 2020-08-09 13:00:00                   2                   1                   7                   8                   9                   1
     51 2020-08-09 11:00:00                   3                   1                   7                   1                   6                   3
```

### supplementary - pick columns that are candidates

Better approach to picking columns to be normalised.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**{"userid": random.randint(1,100), 
 "timestamp":dt.datetime(2020,8,9,random.randint(0,23))},
 **{f"foo_name{f+1}":{f"foo_att{ff+1}":random.randint(1,10) for ff in range(2)} for f in range(3)},
 **{"foo_namex":np.nan},
 **{"foo_namey":"hello"}

} for r in range(5)])

# which columns do we want to convert?
convert = [c[0] 
        for c in df.dtypes.items() 
        if "foo" in c[0] 
           and c[1].name=="object" 
           and isinstance(df.loc[0,c[0]], dict)]

df2 = pd.concat([
    df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c not in convert]]] + # keep the columns not being converted
    [
        pd.DataFrame({f"{c}.{k}":v # rename columns as per requirement
                      for k,v in 
                      # json_normalize is doing all the work,  but requirement to rename columns....
                      pd.json_normalize(df[c]).to_dict(orient="list").items()}) 
        # already worked out list of columns to convert
        for c in convert
], axis=1)
```

Comment: Very nice, where can I learn such advanced usage, in some excerises?

Comment: I just read and assimilate knowledge,  plus 30+ years of coding.... at core is understanding of data structures and algorithms,  writing code is simpler

Comment: Edge case might be is `Nan` value in `foo_nameX` value, instead of dictionary, do we have a trick to adjust  `for k,v in pd.json_normalize(df[c]).to_dict(orient="list").items()`, or solution is to not use dict comprehension and do it in old fashion loop instead, and filter it out?

Comment: @Mulder have done an additional update.  Clearly you can be even more conservative about picking columns... this update just checks that there is a `dict` in first row,  not all rows

Comment: Thanks I guess that I will have to check `NaN` values not in just first row in given column- as each column may have serveral raw, some of them `Nan` some not so in that case maybe I will need to open somhow to adjust code without list comprehension, and check this for each row in column, or I'm missing something?

Comment: default answer use `fillna()` to change `NaN` to doesn't work.  Can't specify a `dict` as fill value...  this code before you convert will deal with it... `for i, c in enumerate(df.loc[0]):
    if isinstance(c, dict):
        df.iloc[df[df.columns[i]].isna(), i] = {"default":np.nan}`. always best to prepare data before processing it