# Pandas: different way to access a string in column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dictionary

I have a df

```
name    manufacturer    information
John    Ford            {'city':'London', 'colour':'black' , 'year': '2017'}
Jane    Porsche         {'city':'Birmingham', 'colour':'red' , 'year': '2019'}
```

I want to create a new_df which contains the values in 'name' and 'colour'

```
name   colour
John   black
Jane   red
```

**Unfortunately, due to the way the data has been preprocessed and the fact that I am provided with a csv only, 'information' is a string (pandas object) rather than a nested dictionary. I'm aware that data should'nt be nested in a single column like this, it is really annoying, but out of my control.**

my current solution is

```
colour_col = []
for i in df['information']:
    colour_col.append(i.split('\'')[7])
df['colour'] = colour_col

new_df = df[['name', 'colour']]
```

This works for now. However, if the position of the 'colour' values is ever changed the code will fall over. Alternatively, code may run but with incorrect data.

Is there an efficient way to achieve new_df that follows best practices? Can I convert the ['information'] column back into a nested dictionary and access the values by a string? Something like new_df = df[information][colour]

**Note: the key strings will not change**

Comment: To be clear, the values in your information column are strings like: `"{'city':'London', 'colour':'black' , 'year': '2017'}"`?

Comment: I've answered a few questions lately on how to expand JSON into columns.  use `pd.concat()` and `pd.json_normalize()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395522/pandas-expending-several-values-to-new-columns-with-some-column-name-manipulat/63397211#63397211

Comment: ALollz - correct, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast` to evaluate those strings into dictionaries, and then let's just grab all the information at once as this is a slow apply. From there you can drop the `'information'` column and work with the normal DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='information'), 
                df['information'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x)))], axis=1)
```

---

```
   name manufacturer        city colour  year
0  John         Ford      London  black  2017
1  Jane      Porsche  Birmingham    red  2019
```

#### Sample Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Jane'], 'manufacturer': ['Ford', 'Porsche'],
                   'information': ["{'city':'London', 'colour':'black' , 'year': '2017'}",
                                   "{'city':'Birmingham', 'colour':'red' , 'year': '2019'}"]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
import json

colour_col = []
for i in df['information']:
    jsonStr = json.loads(i.replace("'", '"'))
    colour_col.append(jsonStr['colour'])

df['colour'] = colour_col
new_df = df[['name', 'colour']]
print(new_df)
```